# Android rendering xml issues in eclipse: Exception raised during rendering: java.util.Locale.toLanguageTag()Ljava/lang/String

Tags: android, android-edittext, rendering, android-xml

My basic functionality and everything are working just fine but there is one thing that is troubling me.
Whenever I use an **EditText** field, the XML fails to render and nothing is displayed. The problem doesn't occur with any other field. I've been getting the following error:
**Exception raised during rendering: java.util.Locale.toLanguageTag()Ljava/lang/String**
Does anyone else face this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be an issue with the API you have set in Eclipse.

If it is set to the Android Wear it may cause this problem.

In the xml Graphic Layout window, look for the android symbol in the top right corner.
There is a drop down arrow, which will list all of the API versions you can use. Check that it is now set to API 20(4.4W.2). You may need to change it to API 19 or API 20 L.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was rendering for Android Wear , and that was causing the problem , setting it to API19 in design view , solved it

Answer (score -1):

1. Clean Your Project and Rebuild.

2.Close Eclipse And Restart again.

3.its Working fine.

Comment: This is not an answer